I'm unable to administor a YouTube Channel
My client created a YouTube channel, using his personal Gmail account, for his business. He's uploaded a number of videos of machinery and equipment that he has sold at auctions he runs. He wants to be able to add more videos as he runs more auctions.
A number of months ago, when we was administering his channel, he says a message popped up suggesting that he move the channel it to his Google Workspace account. He though this was a good idea so he click on whatever it was that he needed to click on to move the channel.
The channel still exists, we can access it by it's channel URL and see the videos that he's uploaded, but now he can't administer the channel in his personal Gmail account or his Google Workspace account.
He's not sure if the channel is personal or brand.
We've tried using Google Workspace support to find out how we can get control of this channel again but because they don't deal with YouTube issues directly, they weren't able to help. They did provide a link to YouTube support, but it looks like that's only helpful to YouTube content partners.
Is anyone able to let me know what process I need to follow to find out what email address the channel is associated with and ultimately recover the ability to administer it.
